# Do I need a visa to travel from India to Nepal?

Tags: visas, india, nepal

I am planning for a one month journey to Kathmandu, Nepal. I have read that Indian citizen does not need to have visa as to travel to Nepal. If so what all identifications/documents should I carry with me. And what all are the procedures?

Comment: are you an Indian national?

Comment: Yeah of course I am.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Indian nationals do not require a visa to enter Nepal**.
As per the Nepalese immigration, Indian nationals traveling to Nepal must posses any one of the following documents:

1. Passport.
2. Driving License with photo.
3. Photo Identity card issued by a Government Agency.
4. Ration Card with Photo.
5. Election Commission Card with Photo  .
6. Identity Card issued by Embassy of India in Kathmandu .
7. Identity Card with photo issued by sub-divisional magistrate or any other officials above his rank.

Also, please check with your nearest travel agents for documents required by the Indian Immigration for Indians traveling to Nepal.
Source: http://www.welcomenepal.com/plan-your-trip/visa-nepal-information.html

Answer (score 5):

Indian nationals do not require visas to travel to Nepal. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens), "Indian citizens may live and work freely in Nepal under the terms of the [1950 Indo-Nepal Treaty of Peace and Friendship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_Indo-Nepal_Treaty_of_Peace_and_Friendship)."

However you are required to provide a valid government photo id card while entering Nepal. Voter's Id Card, Passport, Aadhar card, Driving licence etc are accepted.